# How do I combine "margin:0 28px" and "margin-bottom:13px"?

Tags: css, phpstorm

PhpStorm (my IDE) says that for my CSS

```
div.stepDot {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    bottom:6px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 28px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
```

The margin and margin-bottom lines can be shortened.  What is it trying to say?

Comment: `margin: 0 28px 13px;` = 0 for top value, 28px for left and right value, and 13px for bottom value.

Comment: mozilla firefox shortens the margin/padding property. check it out. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shorthand works like this:

```
margin: top right bottom left;
```

In your code it would be:

```
margin: 0 28px 13px;
```

If you are not specifying all parameters they work like these:

```
margin: top right-left bottom;
margin: top-bottom right-left;
margin: top-right-bottom-left;
```

Comment: Your explanation lists 4 values (top, right, bottom, left) but your code list 3 values (0, 28px, 13px).  That's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The `margin: 0 28px;` specifies the horizontal and vertical margins, so it's the same as `margin: 0 28px 0 28px;` which specifies the top, right, bottom and left margins.

Changing the bottom margin makes the whole effect the same as `margin: 0 28px 13px 28px;`. This can be shortened to `margin: 0 28px 13px;` which specifies the top, vertical and bottom margins.